# How to get rid of chinese in Postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql

I would like to get rid of tags that consist only of chinese, korean, etc.

I found the following to list lines with non-ascii characters:

```
select col from tablename where col ~ '[^[:ascii:]]';
```

How can I change this to list lines consisting only of non-ascii characters?

Comment: Try `where col ~ '^[^[:ascii:]]+$'`

Comment: Definitely finding some, but I don't think it's finding all. Only getting 25 lines, pretty sure there's way more; maybe needs spaces?

Comment: Sorry, only you have the data and can specify the requirements. `^[^[:ascii:]]+$` matches strings that consist of 1 or more non ASCII chars.

Comment: Did not get ызусшфд фпутеы

Comment: "special agents"? Aha, `[:ascii:]` might be locale specific. Maybe you'd better use `'^[^ -~]+$'`?

Comment: Sadly that does not work

Comment: Note there is a space between ызусшфд and фпутеы

Comment: Maybe `^[^a-zA-Z]+$` will do? Or extend it `^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$`, etc.

Comment: Or if you want all non-ascii and spaces - `^([[:space:]]|[^[:ascii:]])+$`

Comment: I'll accept ^[^a-zA-Z]+$ (if you want the credit) even though it brings back numbers as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the most important thing for you is to match a string that does not contain some specified characters.

You need to first identify the chars/ranges you do not want to match, and put them into a *negated* bracket expression.

So, if you need to match string that contain non-ASCII chars only you need to use

```
select col from tablename where col ~ '^[^[:ascii:]]+$';
```

Note that `^` matches the start of string, `[^[:ascii:]]+` matches 1+ chars other than ASCII and `$` matches the end of string.

Now, if you need to match entries that do not contain ASCII letters, replace the pattern with `^[^a-zA-Z]+$`.

If you need to match entries with ASCII letters/digits, use `^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$`.